# Gradle daemon is going into infinity loop after upgrading android studio to 4.2.1

Tags: android-studio

1. This is the image of gradle daemon
   [image]
2. This is the version of the android studio
   [image]

3. and I have tried to change heap size in the gradle properties but it is not working.
4. I am really stuck on this issue because any project is not building and even when I was trying to build new project it is also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving this problem in windows run this command in cmd.

**setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true**

and this will work definetly.

Answer (score 0):

I update to 4.2.1 on my Mac today, when I open up a project it starts an infinity loop of android studio windows of that project, had to hard restart my Mac.

The only way I was able to fix it, was by going back to 4.1.3.

Comment: And what about if we want to use latest features of the android ? 
Is this bug is from the google side ?

Comment: Have you tried Google bug reporting system?
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190923&template=841312&pli=1
I don't know how fast they answer.

Comment: Not working even changed the version. same error

Comment: What happens if start Gradle in cmd instead of Android studio?
$ cd my-project
$ gradle taskName
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html

Comment: The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection. this error is firing brother.